# XamlParseException when opening design with Esri map

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, esri, esri-maps

Today I converted my VS2010SP1, Silverlight 4, Prism4.0, Esri  ArcGis 2.4 application to: VS2012RC and Silverlight 5, Prism4.1 and Esri ArcGis api 3.0.

It uses an Esri map, and I get a strange error while opening an xaml page:

```
XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]

at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
```

I don't have a clue where and how to diagnose this error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Sometimes you get nasty errors when parsing XAML.

In this case the old 2.4 SDK with the new 3.0 SDK was the issue. After uninstalling the 2.4 SDK from Esri, cleaning all obj and debug folders and rebuilding the solution, the XAML was parsed correctly.